# How to make BI Publisher to retrieve the latest data of database?

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, obiee, bi-publisher

I'm working on BI Publisher in OBIEE and I've created a dashboard contains different reports generated from SQL query data models.

The dashboard works well, but when data changed in the database, the dashboard loads old data and seems not to be refresh.

I've found that if I view and save the sample data of data models again, the shown data will be refreshed.

How to make OBIEE to refresh the dashboard automatically or force OBIEE to refresh data models?

Comment: Are you talking about BI Publisher, or Answers? What version of OBIEE? Are you using BI Server caching?

Comment: Hi @Robin the OBIEE guru ;), yes, I'm talking about OBIEE Version 12.2.1.2.0. I don't know about BI Server caching :(. There's a SqlServer database contains some report tables and OBIEE connected to the database.

Comment: Are you using BI Publisher?

Comment: Yes I am using  BI publisher to create reports.

Comment: OK - BI Publisher is separate from what is usually meant by OBIEE (Answers/RPD). I've edited your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration, I'll edit my question as you've mentioned, but my problem's not solved yet :(

Comment: You say "SQL query data models" - like literally writing SQL statements against the data source manually in BIP?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you need to globally disable report caching and/or override caching parameters set at the individual report level.

### Follow these steps (use with caution, as doing the below can contribute to increased server load as you scale your data):

1. Log into the Administration tab and go to System Maintenance - Server Configuration.
2. In the Caching panel set Cache Expiration (minutes) to 0 and bounce the server.

### Alternatively, you could set the Cache duration at the report level:

A.  Report level Caching:  Under report properties>Caching tap :

1. There is box called : Enabled Data Caching: Default: Not enabled

When this property is enabled, the data generated by the online submission of this report will be stored in cache.

The data will remain in the cache according to the time limit specified in the Cache Duration property.

Once the time limit has expired, the next request for the same report will generate a fresh data set.

Note: You can control whether the cache for the report is shared by users by setting the User Level property.

B. Server level Caching: Administration ->Server Configuration->System Maintenance -> Scroll down to see a section "Caching":

a. When BI Publisher processes a report, the data and the report document are stored in cache. Each item creates a separate cache file.
    Set the following properties to configure the size and expiration of this cache:

```
1. Cache Expiration : Enter the expiration period for the cache in minutes. The default is 30

2. Cache Size Limit:   Enter the maximum number of cached items to maintain regardless of the size of these items. The default is 1000.
```

b. When BI Publisher processes a report it stores the report definition in memory so that for subsequent requests for the same report, the report definition can be retrieved from memory rather than from disk. Set the following property to configure this cache:

```
1. Maximum Cached Report Definitions — Enter the maximum number of report definitions to maintain in cache. The default is 50. This cache does not expire.
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit you analysis, go to advanced tab and give SET VARIABLE DISABLE_CACHE_HIT=1; in prefix. Press apply  sql and save the analysis.

Comment: That's relevant for queries against the BI Server only -- not BI Publisher.